# Событие при наведении на legend highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Добрый день!
Есть график

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          showInLegend: true
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: "Brands",
        data: [{
          name: "Safari",
          y: 4.77
        }, {
          name: "Opera",
          y: 0.91
        }, {
          name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
          y: 0.2
        }]
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

, как можно вызвать alert (со значением) при наведение на пункт в legend?

Answer (score 1):

Выделение элемента по ховеру

```
(function (Highcharts) {
        var each = Highcharts.each;

        Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Legend.prototype, 'renderItem', function (proceed, item) {

            proceed.call(this, item);


            var isPoint = !!item.series,
                collection = isPoint ? item.series.points : this.chart.series,
                groups = isPoint ? ['graphic'] : ['group', 'markerGroup'],
                element = item.legendGroup.element;

            element.onmouseover = function () {
               each(collection, function (seriesItem) {
                    if (seriesItem !== item) {
                        each(groups, function (group) {
                            seriesItem[group].animate({
                                opacity: 0.25
                            }, {
                                duration: 150
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            element.onmouseout = function () {
               each(collection, function (seriesItem) {
                    if (seriesItem !== item) {
                        each(groups, function (group) {
                            seriesItem[group].animate({
                                opacity: 1
                            }, {
                                duration: 50
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }           

        });
    }(Highcharts));
```

Взято отсюда http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Ha3Wr/ там же можно увидеть в работе.